# Baby Rudin Theorem 2.35 Proof Explanation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

The theorem states: **Closed subsets of compact sets are compact.**
The proof is:

> Suppose $F\subset K\subset X$, $F$ is closed (relative to $X$), and $K$ is compact. let $\{V_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $F$. If $F^c$ is adjoined to $\{V_\alpha\}$, we obtain an open cover $\Omega$ of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite subcollection $\Phi$ of $\Omega$ which covers $K$, and hence $F$. If $F^c$ is a member of $\Phi$, we may remove it from $\Phi$ and still retain an open cover of $F$. We have thus shown that a finite subcollection of $\{V_\alpha\}$ covers $F$.

My question is are the two "if"s always true? Specifically:

> If $F^c$ is adjoined to $\{V_\alpha\}$...
> If $F^c$ is a member of $\Phi$...

I will admit that I still do not quite understand the concept of open covers and subcovers, so any clarifications on that will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $F^c$ is adjoined to $\{V_\alpha\}$, we obtain an open cover $\Omega$ of $K$.

The $V_\alpha$ are open sets, by definition. $F^c$ is also open (because $F$ is closed). So the $V_\alpha$ with the additional set $F^c$ is a collection of open sets. To see that they form a cover of $X$, it suffices to show that any point of $x$ lies in some set in this collection of open sets. If $x \in K$, then $x \in V_\alpha$ for some $V_\alpha$ (since $\{V_\alpha\}$ is a cover of $K$). Otherwise if $x \in K^c$, then $x \in F^c$ because $F \subset K$.

> If $F^c$ is a member of $\Phi$, we may remove it from $\Phi$ and still retain an open cover of $F$.

$\Phi$ is a finite sub-collection of the collection $\Omega$ that covers $K$.

- If $F^c$ is not a member of $\Phi$, then $\Phi$ covers $F$ (because it covers $K$), and is a finite sub-collection of the $V_\alpha$.
- If $F^c$ is a member of $\Phi$, the claim is that if we remove $F^c$ from $\Phi$, the remaining collection of finitely many open sets would still be an open cover of $F$. But no point of $F$ lies in $F^c$, so $F^c$ is unnecessary for covering $F$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I interpreted the first if as a conditional one, now I understand the proof!

Answer (score 1):

The first condition is a always true: If $F^c$ is adjoined to $\{V_\alpha\}$ you have an open cover of $K$. Indeed the family $M=\{V_\alpha\}\cup\{F^c\}$ satisfies the two conditions required for being an open cover of $K$:

1. Every member of $M$ is open: Every $V_\alpha$ is open, and also $F^c$ is open (as $F$ is closed).
2. Every point $x$ from $K$ (actually even every point $x$ from $X$) is contained in a set from the family $M$: In case $x\in F$, it is contained in some $V_\alpha$ (because $\{V_\alpha\}$ is a cover of $F$), and in case $x\notin F$, $x$ is contained in the set $F^c$.

The second condition you mention is not necessarily true: If $F^c$ does not belong to $\Phi$, it is not necessary to remove it from $\Phi$. The point is that in both cases (whether $F^c$ belongs to $\Phi$ or not), one obtains a finite subfamily of $\{V_\alpha\}$ which covers $F$.

Answer (score 0):

You can reword that first “if“ as:

> Let $\Omega = \{ V_\alpha \} \cup \{F^c\}$.  We see that $\Omega$ is an open cover of $K$.

So it's not so much a conditional “if” statement as a sequential one.

The second “if” statement is the important case of a proof by cases that a finite subset of $\Omega$ covering $K$ gives rise to a finite subset of $\{V_\alpha\}$ covering $F$.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed my misinterpretation of the first "if".

Comment: The case distinction is really in the first step: if the $\{V_\alpha\}$ already cover $K$, proceed and we get a finite subcover and we're done. If *not* we need $F^c$ to make new larger cover to cover all of $K$ and then apply the hypothesis of compactness, and in the resulting finite subcover we also needed $F^c$ but we remove it again to get a subcover for the *original* cover. @LukeHan